# How do I define a variable to be any number?

Tags: racket

I am having trouble defining my this function in **Dr. Racket.**
I want it so that the two numbers I plug in are added to the x and y cordinates.

Except everytime I put in "Number" it says that "Number" is not defined as a variable. How do I get around this? **NOTE:** I want "Number" to be any number that I plug in.

**Here is my code:**

```
(define-struct Cell (x y)) 

(define (adjust cell x y)
((+ x (Number)) (+ y (Number))))
```

**Here is what it should do:**

```
(check-expect (adjust (make-Cell 104 123) 2 -3) (make-Cell 106 120))
```

As you can see 2 is added to 104, and -3 is added to 123 to make: 
(make-Cell 106 120)

Comment: Shouldn't you be referring to the cell's x and y within adjust instead of `Number`, which is clearly undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you understand how structs work in Racket (see http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html). I believe this is what you're looking for. `Cell-x` gets the `x` element of the struct `Cell`, similarly for `y`.

```
(define (adjust cell x y)
(make-Cell (+ x (Cell-x cell)) (+ y (Cell-y cell))))
```

Comment: ahh yes, this seems to be working, and I understand why, however when I do the check-expect, it is giving me this error "function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but received 106"  **Why is that?**

Comment: (check-expect (adjust (make-Cell 104 123) 2 -3) (make-Cell 106 120))

Comment: Ah, I believe this is because Racket is a functional language, i.e. it is stateless, hence you cannot 'edit' the 'pre-existing' cell. If you're used to non-functional languages, you may want to read [Functional Languages in a Nutshell](http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/fp.html). Instead what we do in a functional language is make a new object with the new values. I've updated my answer to address this. Tell me if it works.

Comment: ahh this works now, thank you very much, what was the change you made? I'm looking at this at morning and I completely forgot what the other code was.  You added "make-Cell" right? Because we're making a new object now with new values.